# Theano ValueError: Some matrix has no unit stride

Tags: python, machine-learning, gpu, theano

Recently have run into issues getting predictions for a trained pylearn2 model.  The relevant bits of the traceback are provided below.  I have ensured that `model.get_input_shape()` matches the shape of the numpy array I'm passing in to the theano prediction function I've generated, but still receive the following error.

```
ValueError: some matrix has no unit stride
Apply node that caused the error: Dot22(Elemwise{Composite{[Switch(GT(*1 -> add(i0, i1), i2), *1, i2)]}}[(0, 0)].0, y_W)
Inputs types: [TensorType(float32, matrix), TensorType(float32, matrix)]
Inputs shapes: [(1, 1000), (1000, 1)]
Inputs strides: [(9223372036854775807, 4), (4, 9223372036854775807)]
Inputs scalar values: ['not scalar', 'not scalar']
```

Interestingly enough, behavior seems to be machine-dependent.  I have the prediction script working on my local machine, but execution on a Google Compute Engine instance produces the above error.

Any ideas where I might start debugging?  The input strides look pretty odd, but I'm unsure how to begin debugging that value.

Comment: I've recently spent a lot of time debugging my debugging process for theano. Its powerful but my opinion of it as a tool has been souring

Comment: @Raff.Edward, I'm interested to know more about the problem you had. We already try to improve Theano.

Comment: oof, lots. Trying to print on gradient update - never got that working. Still not sure I created a shared scalar properly. Error messages are terribly confusing. Can't step through the code with a debugger (making the lack of successful printing all the more important). No warnings /way to tell if you accidentally make some code run on the CPU instead of GPU. No way (i found) to make sure biases are paired with weight vectors in an update (say I update a specific bias on L2 norm regularization). The docs don't explain whats happening much either. It was a lot of work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that NumPy create an ndarray with wrong strides. This was fixed in more recent version of NumPy. So update NumPy and it should work.

This is the line that show NumPy strides are bad:

```
Inputs strides: [(9223372036854775807, 4), (4, 9223372036854775807)]
```

Did you compile NumPy with some special flags to test strides for dimensions of size 1?

Here I did a PR to be more tolerant to those invalid strides:

```
https://github.com/Theano/Theano/pull/2008
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks @nouiz.  The issue was complicated by the fact that `sudo python` was using a different python environment than `python` because of the sudoers file.  Executing with `sudo` used an older numpy version, even though I had the dev version from github installed and available when running without sudo permissions.  
Should probably have run this past the theano-users mailing list as well, but thanks for digging this up from StackOverflow.